# flex container can't detect window scrollTop offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

i need to get the `window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;` value.
To determine
1) if user has scrolled over the header 
2) and direction `st < delta && lastScrollTop !== 0`

`$(window).on('scroll', fn)` didn't worked, so i used `$('main').on('scroll', fn)`. It's because I am using

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

But now I can't get the scrolled distanced. Any ideas? [codepen](https://codepen.io/elna-legzdia/pen/YgYqoW) bellow

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;


$(window).on('scroll', () => {
     var st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
     console.log('not triggering', st);
});

$('main').on('scroll', () => {
    var st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    console.log('is triggering', st);
});
```

I am using this solution - https://codepen.io/elna-legzdia/pen/YgYqoW

Comment: `$(window)` not `$('window')`

Comment: Just create another container with `display: block` and then place your flex container inside that container. Then get your `scrollTop` value from the `block` container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally think it's a poor choice to change the display type of the `body` element.  It's the root container and who knows how each browser has specified it's display.  IMHO it's better to create your own root element and start from there.

[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/erikphilips/pen/QoaGyp?editors=1111)

```js
var $main = $('main');
$main.on('scroll', () => {
  var pos = $main.scrollTop();
  var isTop = pos == 0;
  $main.toggleClass('top', isTop);
  var isBottom = pos + $main.innerHeight() >= $main.prop('scrollHeight');
  $main.toggleClass('bottom', isBottom);
  console.log('is triggering', pos);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#root {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sticky-header, .sticky-footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: purple;
}

.sticky-content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: green;
}
.top {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.bottom {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
    <header class="sticky-header">
      <h1>I'm Sticky</h1>
    </header>

    <main class="sticky-content top">
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
      <p>This is a large amount of scrollable content.</p>
    </main>

    <footer class="sticky-footer">
      <small>I'm sticky</small>
    </footer>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using dispay: flex on body element. It's not a good idea, use a div instead. Just remving flex on body (the other elements are good) and you have it working!

<del>display: flex;</del>
   <del>flex-direction: column;</del>

Comment: This solution is for the dynamic height header which is fixed.

Comment: Like Erik and i said, it's a bad design choice. You can achieve the same with other Technic.